# ActiveMQ 5.16.2 Log4J

Tags: log4j, activemq-classic

I tried to search for security Log4J issues regarding ActiveMQ 5.16.2 but I could not find any information.
Does ActiveMQ Version 5.16.2 has the Log4J security problems?
If so what should be done to close this gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might review the [ActiveMQ users mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?users@activemq.apache.org) to stay up-to-date on the latest project activity. All official support and development activities are discussed and documented on the [mailing lists](https://activemq.apache.org/contact). This is standard practice for all Apache projects.

There's also a ["News" section](https://activemq.apache.org/news/) of the ActiveMQ website that may have relevant information like [this update](https://activemq.apache.org/news/cve-2021-44228) regarding CVE-2021-44228.

Comment: Thanks. I will subscribe to that. Do you maybe also have some hints for my other issue regarding AMQ 5.16.2? Unfortunately no one answered yet and I am a bit lost.